# CORS request with AWS API Gateway using x-api-key header

Tags: ajax, amazon-web-services, cors, api-gateway

Trying to get a CORS request working with a really simple REST based APIGateway setup on AWS. I have a basic "hello world" lambda function defined and a GET method attached to the / resource on my gateway. Direct browser GET requests to the API work fine, once I add an API key, attach it to a usage plan and attach that to my testing API curl GET request also work once I add the x-api-key header to my curl request.

However as soon as I enable CORS and try to request the resource using ajax/jquery as part of a script it breaks and I get a 500 server error for the Preflight OPTIONS check and a CORS error for the actual GET request in the browser console :(

I am using https://www.w3schools.com/ to launch my query so have added https://www.w3schools.com to the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` field in the Enable CORS page on AWS. But try as I might it will not work - anyone got any suggestions to to what i'm doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "<MY APIGateway URL>",
    headers: { 
        "x-api-key": "<MY API KEY>"
    },
    success: function(result){
      console.log('Working!')
    }
 });

</script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ah! looks like I was missing a mapping template in the mock Integrations request

Added this and its all working!

{
    "statusCode": 200
}

Will do a bit more digging and then mark as answered...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue was indeed with the Mock OPTIONS integration request. Running Test in the AWS UI returned a 500 server error. Had to add a 200 OK Mapping template to the Mock Integrations Request. Once done it all works :)

```
{
    "statusCode": 200
}
```

https://cloudnamaste.com/500-internal-server-error-mock-integration/